# Pimcore: Setting DateTime Class Fields on Objects

Tags: datetime, field, variable-assignment, pimcore

I'm writing an importer and am getting stuck with actually creating the objects. Specifically, I'm having troubles with DateTime fields. I have a class called `blogArticle` and I'm using them just as the Pimcore demo data uses them for blog articles.

```
$newPost = new Object\BlogArticle();
$newPost->setCreationDate( time() );
$newPost->setPublished( true );

$newPost->setText( $text );      // text input field
$newPost->setTitle( $title );    // text input field
$newPost->setDate( $date );      // datetime input field

$newPost->setKey( \Pimcore\File::getValidFilename( $key ) );
$newPost->setParentId( $id );
$newPost->save();
```

The exact error I am getting is:

```
Whoops\Exception\ErrorException thrown with message "Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object"

Stacktrace:
#0 Whoops\Exception\ErrorException in /.../pimcore/models/Object/ClassDefinition/Data/Datetime.php:73
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation apart from how the value is stored in the database for this field type. Literally zero documentation on how to appropriately assign values to class fields per field type.

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Igor Benko on solving this one!

```
$newPost_date = new DateTime( "2016-07-01 12:10:37" );
$newPost->setDate( $newPost_date );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your system is still set to use the Zend_Date. DateTime is used only if you have a clean install of Pimcore 4, otherwise the compatibility layer is turned on by default after the update. The compatibility layer uses Zend_Date instead.

In your system.php you have to turn the flag **useZendDate** to **false** in order to use DateTime class.

You need to pass an instance of DateTime class to the setter. Something like this:

```
$date=new DateTime("2016-07-01 12:10:37");
$newPost->setDate($date);
```

See this:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Update+from+Version+3.x+to+Version+4#UpdatefromVersion3.xtoVersion4-PHP%27sDateTimereplacesZend_Date

EDIT: Updated the answer after @GrafikMatthew updated his question.

Comment: We did use the Clean Install version of Pimcore 4. I will check this setting and report back. Thanks.

Comment: So assigning an integer is not the correct way to set this field value? Is there a section that I'm not seeing in the documentation which explains the correct input format for setting fields?

Comment: See this: https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854212   "In the database its data is saved as unix timestamp and thereby stored in an INT data column. Programmatically these data types are represented by a DateTime Object." It's not really obvious. But your best bet is to just check what can you pass to the setDate method - any good IDE should give you a hint.

Comment: Ah, I'm not using an IDE, I'm using SublimeText. Any IDE you suggest that works well for Pimcore?

Comment: @GrafikMatthew PhpStorm is amazing and it will greatly improve your experience with Pimcore. I highly recommend it, although it might not be as snappy as Sublime, it will save you a lot of time. But reading the source code of Pimcore will help you a lot and a good IDE makes it very easy.

Comment: I was just looking at PHPStorm. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: When facing such problems as this, you can just press Ctrl/Cmd+P within method call brackets and it will show what parameters you can pass. You can hold Ctrl/Cmd and click on the method and you will see method's source code. Makes everything much more clear.